# Fix jQuery setInterval and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I wrote this code to get new data from a database, but I don't know what is wrong with this code and why I'm getting the following error in the browser console.

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var lastdate = $("#countcomment").attr("loadtime");
        $.post("update.php",{ajax:"1", lastdate:lastdate},function(data){
            if(data.getnew){
                $('#countcomment').html(data.getnew);
                $('#countcomment').attr('loadtime', ""+data.new)
            }
        }, "json");
    }, 1000);
});
```

PHP:

```
$database = $db->super_query("
    SELECT count(*) as count 
    FROM ".PREFIX."_comments 
    WHERE date >= '$real_date' 
");

$newcomments = $database['count'];

if($newcomments > "0"){
    echo "{\"getnew\":\"{$newcomments}\",\"new\":\"{$now_date}\"}";
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="countcomment" loadtime="2013"></span>
```

The Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getnew' of null
```

I don't know what is the problem!

Comment: you should verify first that data is being returned properly throught console, console.log(data);

Comment: I don't know if this will fix your problem, but you might want to try `$response = array('getnew' => $newcomments, 'new' => $now_date); echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: @Rooster, how? i need more help i think.

Comment: @Alireza comment out the whole if(data.getnew) block and replace it with console.log(data);  then open up your console run the code and verfiy it shows the json.  if it says null your doing something else wrong.

Comment: @Rooster, thank you. i found the problem. it was in PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your server sends more data than you expect (e.g. errors).
Use the following js code to check response data:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function() {
  var lastdate = $("#countcomment").attr("loadtime");
  $.post("update.php",{ajax:"1", lastdate:lastdate},function(data, status, xhr){
     console.log(xhr.responseText)
     },"json");
  }, 1000);
});
```

Or you can see that data in "Network" tab in Chrome's Developer Tools